Thread-insafe examples are behaving in a thread-safe way, is their a reliable way to demonstrate the problems that Locks resolve?
I am trying to create small examples using Locks to demonstrate the issues that Locks will resolve in a multi-threaded environment.
The example I created is the following,
import threading

# Shared mutable list
shared_list = []

def append_to_list(value):
    for _ in range(1000):
        shared_list.append(value)

# Create multiple threads
threads = []
for i in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=append_to_list, args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(shared_list)

The code output is [0,0,0, ..., 1, 1, 1, ...] whereas I was expecting a non-perfect sequential list such as [0,0,1,0,1, ...]. However, it seems to be in a exact sequential order throughout the entire list. Is their a way to modify this behaviour to create a clear and reliably reproducible to demonstrate why threading Locks are necessary?

Python has GIL, which reduces code execution to single-core execution. One consequence of this is that every Python thread is subject to preemptive multitasking, in which each thread has exclusive execution (acquires the GIL) for a period of time called a timeslice. That is, no thread will allow to switch execution to another thread until its timeslice expires or some other situation causes it to release the GIL.
Your append_to_list() function has time to execute in one timeslice, thus preventing other threads from executing at the same time, which is your problem. There are many ways to "solve" such problem, which are not really solutions and do not guarantee reproducibility. Here are the most simple, yet effective ones:

Increase the amount of time spent on each thread, that is, increase the number of iterations. This is the most resource-intensive method, but it works in any environment because it simply forces the thread to do more work than one timeslice.
Decrease the timeslices via sys.setswitchinterval(seconds). The default value is 5 milliseconds, and you can set a small enough value, such as 5 microseconds, that thread switching can be performed even with a small number of iterations.
Add time.sleep(0) right after shared_list.append(value) so that the thread can prematurely release the GIL. This way, the thread will not have to wait for the timeslice to expire, but you will have to place such "switches" wherever necessary.

You can also change the environment to get more accurate behavior:

On PyPy, switching between threads is "more aggressive", and you can even see race conditions that are theoretically possible but practically impossible on standard CPython, such as the fixed race in Thread.join().
With free-threaded CPython, you will no longer have the GIL and threads will be able to switch freely by the operating system. This makes switching between threads more chaotic, but it does not eliminate the problem, because a sequential execution will still be possible.

Using these methods, you can very easily make your example almost always reproducible. The key word is almost. You will still have a chance that your example will not reproduce, and this is especially a problem in thread-safety tests. If this is enough for you, you can stop, but if you are interested in the more serious part of this answer, I present the part below for you.

The first place to start is with how to test code. print(shared_list) is a clear example, but it requires human assistance and performs very poorly when there are too many iterations or threads. So let's look at possible alternatives.

The simplest is shared_list != sorted(shared_list). The point is that if the list is sorted, then switching has not affected the order of operations. However, there is a problem: there is no guarantee that the first started thread will start execution first. In particular, [9, ..., 9, 8, ..., 8, ...] does not mix threads either, but shared_list != sorted(shared_list) will give True.
The harder one is sum(1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(shared_list)) != 10. Here we check that the number of subsequences of identical elements is not equal to the number of threads, i.e. we check that there was at least one switch during the execution of at least one thread. This check does not depend on the scheduler, but it is not universal.
Instead of checking the list after threads are executed, we can do it in-process.

At this point, it is time to invent a new example. I propose the following:
import sys
import threading
import time

sys.setswitchinterval(5e-6)  # 5 us

insafe = False
unlocked = [True]

def work():
    global insafe

    for _ in range(1000):
        try:
            unlocked.pop()
        except IndexError:
            insafe = True
        else:
            time.sleep(0)  # or any complex code
            unlocked.append(True)

# Create multiple threads
threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=work)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(insafe)

This example takes advantage of a good property: all the simplest operations on standard Python containers are thread-safe. This is how a simple "guard" is built, which prevents more than one thread from entering a critical section - unlocked.pop() is the same in meaning as lock.acquire(), and unlocked.append(True) as lock.release(), but instead of waiting, the former raises an IndexError. In fact, there are elements of atomic programming here.
Now let's ask ourselves: what is the point of the number of iterations? Actually, it is like flipping a coin: the more we flip a coin, the more likely we are to get the other side. Even if the coin is very biased, the chance will increase with each attempt. And in the case of this example, it is the chance that the execution switches in the critical section.
What we actually need is seconds, not iterations. Thread switching depends on the timeslices, not on the number of operations, so on old hardware fewer iterations will be needed, while on modern hardware, on the contrary, more. Let's modify the example:
import sys
import threading
import time

sys.setswitchinterval(5e-6)

stop = False
insafe = False
unlocked = [True]

def work():
    global insafe

    while not stop:
        try:
            unlocked.pop()
        except IndexError:
            insafe = True
        else:
            time.sleep(0)  # or any complex code
            unlocked.append(True)

# Create multiple threads
threads = []
for _ in range(10):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=work)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

time.sleep(1)  # 1 second
stop = True

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print(insafe)

Now we have an example with great reproducibility, the accuracy of which is tuned based on how much time you are ready to spend. With this knowledge, you can not only demonstrate thread-insafety with simple examples, but also basic code testing for thread-safety. This answer leaves behind the scenes topics such as O(n²) wakeup complexity, which further confirms just how complex multithreading is.
